# laravel validator and error collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering how you access the laravel validator errors after you have performed validation, what I want to to accomplish is creating a new Model with data then validate it with the validator object then store that Model's id and error message in an array then do a loop in my blade page and out put the error information. Can someone have a look at my code and correct any mistakes and help guide me to make the code do what needs to be done - thanks

```
public function store() {

     $products = [];
     $id = Input::get('id'); // multiple id's
     $title = Input::get('title');  // multiple title's
     $price = Input::get('price');  // multiple price's

     for ($i=0, $c = count($id); $i<$c; ++$i) {
         $product = New Product([
             'id' => $id[$i],  
             'title' => $title[$i],
             'price' => $price[$i]
         ]);

         $validator = Validator::make(
            $data = $product,
            Product::$rules,
            Product::$rulesMessages
        );  

        // below is what I think I need to do need sum help
        if($validator->fails()) {
            $record = [];
            $record["id"] = $product=>id; // is this right
            $record["errors"] = $validation->errors(); // how do you get errors
        }

        $products[] = $record;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The validator has a method ->messages() which returns an instance of the MessageBag class, filled with the generated errors (in case the validator failed).

```
$validator->messages()->toArray();
```

will give you an array with all the errors.